# Cannot convert value of type 'Data?' to expected argument type 'UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimagepngrepresentation

I'm trying to get the data of an image but I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Data?' to expected argument type 'UIImage'

The code:

```
if let image = profileImageView.image {
    if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.pngData()) {
        PFUser.current()?["photo"] = PFFileObject(name: "profile.png", data: imageData)
    }
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: `if let imageData = image.pngData()` OR `if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`, don't do it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initializer of `UIImagePNGRepresentation` takes a `UIImage` instance not `Data` instance  , so replace

```
if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.pngData()) {
```

with

```
if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
```

OR better use the latest  [Way](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624096-pngdata)

```
if let imageData = image.pngData() {
```

Comment: FYI - If the `pngData` method is available then attempting to use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` will result in a deprecation warning.

Comment: @rmaddy `pngData()` was introduced in Swift 4.2 , and added that way because i recommend it more than the old way

Comment: I get that. But it makes no sense to recommend using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` when `pngData` is available. We know `pngData` is available to this user because they are using it.

Comment: Swift 5 converting image to data is: JPEGIMAGE.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)